# Hashtable finding the load

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a question about figuring our the load of a hashtable. So the number of objects present in the hashtable. I know that when there is more than 60% of objects in the hashtable array, then the efficiency will be reduced.

I add my "add" method so you can see how im adding the objects into the hashtable.
For some reason, the Load always returns as 0.

```
class MyHashTable<T>{
private T[]values;
private int size;
//hash table size increases 10^n
public MyHashTable(){
    size = 0;
    values = (T[])(new Object[10]);
}
 public void add(T object){
    size = values.length;
    //checks if the # of stuff in the array is over 60%
    //expand if true
    if ((size+10)/size > 0.6){
        size*=2;
        T[]tmp = (T[]) (new Object[size]);
        for(int i=0; i<size/10; i++){
            if (values[i]!=null){
                add(values[i],tmp);
            }
        }
        values = tmp;
    }
    add(object, values);
}

public void add(T object, T[]values){   
    int location = Math.abs(object.hashCode())%values.length;
    while(values[location]!=null){
        location = (location+1)%values.length;
    }
    //System.out.println(object.hashCode());
    values[location] = object;
}
public int getLoad(){
    int load = 0;
    int location = 0;
    while(values[location]!=null){
        load+=1;
        location = (location+1)%values.length;
    }
    return load;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `add(T object)` method.
You start by checking the load factor

```
 //checks if the # of stuff in the array is over 60%
 //expand if true
 if ((size+10)/size > 0.6){
 ....
```

There are two problems here.

The only way this could evaluate to `false` is when size is negative.

Suppose `size = 10`
then `size +10 / size` = `20/10` = `2`

This is probably no the intention of this line of code

The other problem is that this is an integer division which will return an integer. You'll have to cast the `size` to `double` or multiply by `1.0` before doing the division to get a `double` in return.